# Connect Android device with Virtual COM Port device

Tags: android, usb

So i need to connect Android device with [this](http://neatorobotics.com).

The robot is running an API command interpreter on the USB port. Connection to the robot is made through a USB cable. The driver converts the USB port connection to a Com port connection.

I have htc hero with android 2.3.4 on board. But i can buy 4.0 tablet if i have to.

I have found [the tutorial that covers the Serial library. This library allows you to connect with other Bluetooth devices using virtual serial ports (RFCOMM).](http://www.basic4ppc.com/forum/basic4android-getting-started-tutorials/6908-android-serial-tutorial.html) I want to do the same thing but using usb connection.

Also i have found [API to connect, read and write data through theses serial ports](http://code.google.com/p/android-serialport-api/), but i don't think i really need this.

I'm in the begging of the development, so any help would be appreciated. I'm looking for some library or code sample that allows me to use virtual com port on android. something like [this](http://slickdevlabs.com/slick-usb-2-serial-library/).

edited:

found something [here](http://www.cygnal.org/ubb/Forum9/HTML/002248.html) not sure if it will help.